# vba interval only works when workbook is open or when I press F5

Tags: excel, vba

I have another spreadsheet(name: positions) that gets real-time stock quotes, therefor the values in certain cells change every second.  I also create a module that runs a code(calcualteTableValues) in which I can press F5 and it will run no problem.  When I try to run calcualteTableValues in intervals of 3 seconds the code below does not run in the specified interval.  When I press F5 in the workbook_open sub it works but the interval part does not seem to continue.  Please let me know what I am doing wrong.
Thanks

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"), "calcualteTableValues"
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you indeed have `calcualte`?

Comment: yes, because when I press F5 with in sub it runs.  It just doesn't continue to run in the specified interval

Comment: Do you indeed have `calcualte` as opposed to `calculate`?

Answer (score 0):

`OnTime` will run the sub once, to make it a "loop" you need to have another `OnTime` inside that sub, so it calls for itself to run again.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"), "calcualteTableValues"
End Sub
Sub calcualteTableValues()
    ''''''''''''''''
    'code goes here'
    ''''''''''''''''
    
    
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"), "calcualteTableValues"
End Sub
```

If you have spelled the name correctly, but are still having trouble running the sub, try adding the module name to it like `"Module1.calcualteTableValues"` or `"ThisWorkbook.calcualteTableValues"`.

If the sub is part of a separate VB Project, you may also need to  put the project name into the string like `"VBProject1.Module1.calcualteTableValues"`.